# Cant append "used" DOMObject in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some objects, that keep created DOMObjects, like here:

```
function category(){
    var domBlock;
    this.block = function(){
        if (!domBlock){
           // Here dom-object constructor $('<div></div>'); etc
        }
        return domBlock; // jquery object,
               // but i test and native document.createElement
    }
 }
```

Then i clear category's area, and append old and new received(with Ajax) objects:

```
area.html('');
for(id in category_list){
     area.append( category_list[id].block() );
}
```

where category_list is list that contain category objects. Area is jQuery  object.

In other browsers (except IE) i get area with all needed categories, but in IE i get only new received categories(that just create DomObject), other old objects that keeped old DomObject not show.

I know it possible make with innerHTML, but i wont keep DomObject, not text. Because DomObject keep many events. And it very hard for browser attach events for each DomObject after refresh area.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's clone?

Comment: @Kerry
Yep! It's work! Realy i don't knew about this method. But i think that problem was in IE, when it clear innerHTML attribute ob object here destroy all child nodes. And destroy it in my object)

Comment: Nice) I get next problem)
Events don't clone with .clone() method;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like comments suggest you can use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for this, to eliminate your *other* problem, with events not copying, that's covered as well. [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) takes a boolean parameter, telling it whether to copy data and events (this is as of jQuery 1.4, it was just events, not data, before then).

To use [`.clone(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and get a copy including event handlers, just do this:

```
return domBlock.clone(true);
```